# iOS: Google Play Games leaderboard score doesn't update after the first score

Tags: ios, iphone, google-play-games

I have a Google Play Games leaderboard (timestamp, lower is better) that I post scores to from an iOS/Android game. On Android, all of the scores update properly as a player get's lower and lower times, but on iOS, only the very first score ever registered actually gets saved.

On iOS I submit the leaderboard score like so:

```
GPGScore *newScore = [[GPGScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardId:leaderboardId];
newScore.value = score;

[newScore submitScoreWithCompletionHandler: ^(GPGScoreReport *report, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: Unable to post Leaderboard[%@] score[%ld] due to: %@", leaderboardId, score, error.description);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Score submitted successfully. %lld", report.highScoreForLocalPlayerAllTime.value);
    }
}];
```

The thing is, every time you submit a score, the second log message shows with the proper score ("Score submitted successfully."). However, the score never actually updates in the GPG leaderboard.

Comment: I am not seeing the behavior with numeric scores, what is the value you are setting in score?

Comment: It's a long (time in milliseconds it took to complete the level). The long is computed the same way on Android & iOS (C++ game). Android works fine, iOS fails to register the lower/better score.

Comment: Looking into this further, might be a bug.